# Links shown in organic keywords in Google Analytics

Tags: seo, google-analytics, keywords

While using Google Analytics, I have observed that many a times some URLs of my website are themselves shown as the keywords. I think its very odd that my users would type complete URL in Google search.

So, how do URLs get into the keyword section? I am attaching a screenshot where you can see some of the URLs:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you were to search for a URL, Google usually shows you a search result of that page.  I tend to search for URLs to:

- Verify that it is indexed by Google
- See a cached copy
- Get access to content that would otherwise need registration (like New York Times articles)

Given that it is only one visitor that has searched for each of the URLs reported by Google Analytics, it is very possible that a user *has* been searching for some of your URLs.

Comment: Daily about 2000 visitors use url as the query for my website. I don't think someone else is that interested in checking whether a link to my website has been indexed